# Error: suspense.resolve() is called without a pending branch (Vue 3)

Tags: vuejs3, vue-suspense

I keep getting this error and I'm not sure why. Everything seem to work well but I'm still getting this error. Does anyone know what it really means? I cannot find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue with this template:

```
<template>
  <Suspense>
    <div class="w-full h-full">
        <NotAuthenticated v-if="!isAuthenticated"/>
        <Authenticated v-else/>
    </div>
  </Suspense>
</template
```

I think the issue is that when `isAuthenticated` was changed from `false` to `true`, suspense is having trouble finding the pending state because the async components are not direct children.

This refers to [this paragraph in the doc](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html#loading-state):

> Once in a resolved state,  will only revert to a pending state if the root node of the #default slot is replaced. New async dependencies nested deeper in the tree will not cause the  to revert to a pending state.